# Where to write Users Notification code (like Stack Exchange in stack overflow ) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create user notification like `facebook notificaiton`.

`Manish sent you a friend request.`

`Ryan accepted your friend request.`

in an overlay div.

Now, I wish to ask you Where (which controller, Should I write code). and How should I call that in `aplication.html.haml` view.

Note: As Notification will be shown in all pages of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code in the application controller as this code should be common and applicable to all. Declare the helper method in your application controller to make it accessible in the view.

It should be like following as a general idea -

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      protect_from_forgery
      helper_method :user_notifications

      private

      def user_notifications
       #your stuff here..
      end
    end
```

Now in your application.html.erb view, simply call this method.